# How do I compare a background Image resource TextView with a R.drawable.bg_image for switch

Tags: android, textview

Sorry for my bad English.

I have one TextView and it have a Background image resource. But i need when i click in this TextView the Android compare the current Background image resource with a one of R.drawable.bg_images in drawable folder.

bg_image_1
bg_image_2

if the TextView setBackgroundImageResource is bg_image_1 and i click on it, switch TextView background image to gb_image_2 resource.

how?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't get a drawable's resource id after setting this drawable as a background. But you can store some kind of flag or even a resource id somewhere outside your `TextView` or maybe in its tag field. In this case you'll be able to get it and compare with another id.

```
Object tag = textView.getTag();
int backgroundId = R.drawable.bg_image_2;
if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == backgroundId) {
    backgroundId = R.drawable.bg_image_1;
}
textView.setTag(backgroundId);
textView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundId);
```

Comment: Tanks for answer, The TextView is inside in GridView i try get this in  method setOnItemClickListener, i get the TextView.. How i use this flag?

Comment: I have a problem whit this code. when the TextView is out of visualization screen, and i need scroll gridview and click in textview, i have one erro in Object tag = textView.getTag(); in getChildrenAtPosition(position) inside setOnItemClickListener do not get this children position = 47. textview = null.

Comment: I think you have to check whether `textView` is `null` or not.

Comment: `((Integer)tag).intValue()` can be replaced by `(Integer)tag` in above code