# Android: How to compare resource of an image with R.drawable.imagename?

Tags: java, android, imageview, listener

I am working on a sample application in which I need to get the resource of an image view in a onClick listener and compare that with the image source that I know exists. If the resources are the same, I want to launch another intent. The problem I am facing right now is to access that ImageView (and hence its resource Id integer) to compare to the drawable resource.

```
@Override
// should int be final ??
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
// This is not working and I need to find a way to solve this >>
                if (((ImageView)v).getResources().getInteger(0) == R.drawable.imageToCompare)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    // do something         
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a drawable id from an `ImageView`. But if you set it from code, you can also store it somewhere, for example in the tag field. Take a look at the similar question: [Who I compare an background Image resource TextView with a R.drawable.bg_image for switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6309730/170842).

Comment: If I can't get a drawable's resource, is there any other way to find out which ImageView (out of a grid) the user has clicked? Would I be able to use position? and if yes, how? Thanks for the response.

Comment: If it's about `GridView`, you should use `GridView.setOnItemClickListener()`. Here's the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(((ImageView)v).getDrawable().getConstantState() == MainActivity.this
                        .getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unlock)
                        .getConstantState()))
{

// Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to user `setTag()` and `getTag`. I guess you are making your own adapter.

In the method `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, you set tag to `Imageview` when you add other properties to it.

```
ImageView temp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);
temp.setImageResource(icon);
temp.setTag(icon); //drawable unique ID will be my identifier here
```

Then in the `onClick` you simply compare `View v` with your `drawable` id. For example, I wanted to change image on click and I coded it this way. **Take notice how I also change tag when I set a new drawable**

```
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((Integer)v.getTag() == R.drawable.current_img) {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_img);
                    v.setTag(R.drawable.new_img);
                } 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
  if((pic1.getDrawable().getConstantState() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.addpics).getConstantState()))
    {
      //do something
    }
```