# How to check if image of imageview is not changed

Tags: android, imageview

I have a problem like this
in `ImageView`, by default I set `ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar)`
And when I click button "Save", if image in `ImageView` is not changed, it should not save image. I tried this, but it's not working

```
private Drawable oldDrawable;
```

in onCreate()

```
oldDrawable = imgAvatarDoctor.getDrawable();
```

and in button click

```
 if (imgAvatarDoctor.getDrawable() == oldDrawable) {
            isNoError = false;
        }
```

So how can i fix that? thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use bitmap instead,

```
private Bitmap oldDrawable;

oldDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) ivImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

 if (oldDrawable == oldDrawable) {
        isNoError = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use setTag and getTag for comparison of your drawable like this:

initially set tag of your imageview to 0 in your onCreate

```
imgAvatarDoctor.setTag("0");
```

and whenever you change the imageview you can change the tag for something other than 0 like:

```
imgAvatarDoctor.setTag("UpdatedTag");
```

Now on your click listener you can do this:

```
if (imgAvatarDoctor.getTag().equalsIgnoreCase("UpdatedTag")){
//your image view is updated
} else {
// your image view is not update
}
```

Happy Coding !!!!!

Comment: I take photo from Firebase Storage, so I have to check one time if user don't choose image in the first time user login. :'( I need solution to solve this problem :)

Comment: Following link will help you to compare the drawables of your imageview with the one stored in drawable folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353170/android-how-to-compare-resource-of-an-image-with-r-drawable-imagename

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag to trigger image change. 
In onCreate()

```
imageChanged = false;
```

And in function which gets changed image(i.e. onActivityResult), update this flag as

```
imageChanged = true;
```

then on save button click you can easily check for this flag :

```
if(imageChanged)
   //save image
else
   //pass
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting the image, set any tag to the image

```
image.setTag(res); //here, res is drawableID
```

While checking the ID of image, you can use this tag to compare:

```
int oldImage = image.getTag();  //oldImage will be same as drawable ID
```

Now you can compare oldImage with drawable ID of that image and check whether its updated or not.