# Compare Images in Android

Tags: java, android

I am creating Tic Tac Toe game.This is the click event- when a button is clicked set `background image ==num1`

```
public void onClick(View event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(btn1 ==event){
        btn1.setBackgroundResource(num1);
     }
     if(btn2 ==event){
        btn2.setBackgroundResource(num1);
      } 
      if(btn3 ==event){
        btn3.setBackgroundResource(num1);
      }
```

And the three buttons show the same image and the image is set like this

```
if(!(turn % 2 ==0)){
    num1=(R.drawable.nought);
}
else
    num1=(R.drawable.cross);
```

So that problem is now I need to compare these images to check if they are all the same. How do i do that?

Comment: you mean, if they are same "byte per byte", even if they have different id?

Comment: just if the images are similar e.g if the 3 buttons are crosses. I have tried setId() but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to check what the backgrounds are, but why don't you just save the values in a 2D array? -1 for unmarked, 0 for O's, 1 for X's or whatever. It might be better performance wise too (not that I expect tic-tack-toe to be super intensive to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

here I think there is a similar question.

[Who I compare an background Image resource TextView with a R.drawable.bg_image for switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309730/who-i-compare-an-background-image-resource-textview-with-a-r-drawable-bg-image-f)

you can store the id of every button.

Is there something like button.getBackgroundResource()?

You can overwrite ImageButton class and add the id of the backgroundResource.

Comment: Theres only getBackground()